# Hourly spam for Delhi site

Tags: discussion, spam, abuse

Various Stack Exchange sites seem to be getting one spam per hour for this organization, with a break for a good night's sleep:

https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?body=growmewise.com

The search results presently start yesterday at 06:50 UTC and continue with roughly one per hour until 10:58 UTC, then start again this morning at 05:00 UTC on a similar schedule.  (This corresponds to 12:20 through 16:28, starting again at 10:30, Delhi time, which is the location of the service they are advertising.)

The IP address has reverse DNS indicating it belongs to webhostbox.net, and DNS is also handled by this provider.  The [whois registration](https://who.is/whois/growmewise.com) appears to reveal the registrant's real name and contact information.  The netblock (and the webhostbox.net domain name?) belong to publicdomainregistry.com, apparently an operation in India.

I am collecting this documentation here to hopefully help coordinate contacts with this provider.  I will be sending them an email shortly.

To nominally turn this into a question, what more could we do to dissuade them from spamming us?

Comment: Most of the spam measures here tend to be getting rid of spam quickly, and kicking em out. Granted I'm not an insider but I don't think SE's typically gone after spammers or their hosts directly.

Comment: I have done this as a volunteer a few times.  The purpose of this post is mainly to document that I'm doing this, and perhaps collect additional suggestions.  Ideally, the hosting provider will reply here and tell us the problem is resolved, but that's not usually what happens...

Comment: I've gone into volunteer mode and chased people who have spammed sites belonging to friends of mine, but it always ends up the same result. The person responsible will be using someone else's server they have accessed illegally, the owner of the server and the domain are likely unaware of the problem. Making them aware will allow them to plug the holes in their security, but ultimately the culprits will just move on, there are always more servers with poor security out there

Comment: For what it's worth, a previous attempt at Stack Overflow seems to have eventually worked, in that one of the high-profile spammers went away. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332634/874188 That "question" is arguably a failed experiment, but I hope I'm learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am hesitantly calling this handled because the spam on SE sites stopped.

I thought it was not just on Stack Exchange sites but in Google hits as well, but reviewing Google hits by date shows that they are still at it.

https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&q=growmewise.com&tbs=qdr:w,sbd:1